# How is the iadd operator ( += ) different than simple addition?

Tags: python, syntax

I always thought `x += 1` was just syntactic shorthand (and exactly equivalent to) `x = x + 1`, until I spent a while trying to figure out why this code wasn't acting as intended:

```
[ipython/euler 72 ]$ def func(mylist):
    mylist += random.sample(range(100),2)
    # do stuff with the random result, then restore original list
    mylist = mylist[:-2]
```

It's supposed to return the same list it gets, but it doesn't seem to work that way:

```
[ipython/euler 81 ]$ x = [1,2,3]

[ipython/euler 82 ]$ func(x)
[1, 2, 3, 23, 7]

[ipython/euler 83 ]$ func(x)
[1, 2, 3, 23, 7, 42, 36]

[ipython/euler 84 ]$ func(x)
[1, 2, 3, 23, 7, 42, 36, 0, 5]
```

If I change the assignment statement to the long form `mylist = mylist + ...`, it works as expected and leaves the list unchanged.

Why is this happening? I assume it has to do with lists being mutable and possibly iadd not being 'real' addition when called as an overloaded method of list, but I still expected the interpreter to see them as equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first code (`mylist += random.sample(range(100),2)`) modifies the list *in place*, as you've realised.

Both of these:

```
mylist = mylist + ...
mylist = mylist[:-2]
```

create a *new* object called `mylist`, which is then given the same value as (or one derived from) the previous `mylist`.

The latter line does not restore the original list for this reason; it's creating a new copy, and leaving the original reference alone.

You can get your desired behaviour by changing the list in place:

```
mylist[:] = mylist[:-2]
```

Comment: Thanks! Now, I know why.

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
mylist += random.sample(range(100),2)
```

mutates the list `mylist` in-place (that's why it's called `iadd`: in-place add). This means that it changes the original list in the caller's scope.

```
mylist = mylist[:-2]
```

creates a new *local*  object `mylist` and assigns the contents of global `mylist[:-2]` to it. This new local object is then discarded immediately upon returning from the function.

Comment: Tempted to downvote because of the remark about `global`... If he had added `global mylist`, his original list would still be called `x` and thus the code would definitely not behave as expected; and using globals for this is certainly not the way to go. You'd either want to copy the list at the beginning or modify it in-place all the way through, e.g. using `pop` twice instead of slicing at the end.

Comment: @l4mpi: You're right, I should remove this. Thanks.